# Trouble with css scroll bars

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with css scroll bars working the way I need them to. I have a modal footer that pulls JPG images via ajax. I have 3 `div` elements, side by side within that modal footer, one for each type of photo I'm pulling.

I want all the photos to flow horizontally within their respective divs with horizontal scrollbars only if needed and no vertical scroll bars at all. The pictures are 75x75 pixels each. I have the following code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
            <div id="photodiv" class="pull-left" style="padding:0px 2px; max-width:300px; max-height:80px; overflow: auto; border:1px solid gray;">
                <div id="photoProgress" class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div><h3>Looking for photos...</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div id="notePhotoDiv" class="pull-left" style="padding: 0px 2px; max-width: 300px; max-height: 80px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid gray;">
                <div id="noteProgress" class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div><h3>Looking for progress notes...</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div id="pathPhotoDiv" class="pull-left" style="padding: 0px 2px; max-width: 300px; max-height: 80px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid gray;">
                <div id="pathProgress" class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:100%;"></div>
                </div>
                <div><h3>Looking for path reports...</h3></div>
            </div>
            <p>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="save" value="Save" />
                <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
            </p>
        </div>
```

I have tried changing overflow property in all sorts of different ways and can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried adjusting overflow-x, overflow-y, overflow, I've tried changing from auto to hidden, scroll, visible.

The code currently has vertical scroll bars only. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I unfortunately can't provide a jsfiddle because it's for an intranet site and is pulling photos from an internal server. If need be I can provide screenshots of what it looks like.

Comment: So, you want three divs side by side, and within each of those divs, you want images to scroll via a horizontal scrollbar. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you're looking for. The problem is that you probably need `white-space:nowrap;` to keep the images in a line rather than wrapping to the next line. See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/F8JPq/